# Unable to convert a string indexed array back and forth using JSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
var a =[]
a["sheet1"] = "hi"
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
var c =JSON.parse(b)
```

Now `c["sheet1"]` returns `undefined`

Any workaround for this? Is that a bug in the JSON for JS?

EDIT:

The problem with using an object is, I have strings like `"abc"` . So if like `var k = "abc"`. and `a={}`. I can not call `a.k` . It returns

`TypeError: XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({})`

I can not use `a.abc` because `"abc"` coming as a string from somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an array. Use an object.

Change

```
var a = [];
```

to

```
var a = {};
```

When you convert an Array to JSON, only the numeric indexes will be encoded. Everything else will be dropped.

Comment: Obviously, I understand that. But shouldn't JSON index non-numeric index as well?

Comment: No. Array indices are only defined for integers. Quoting the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), "Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a 
String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2³²-1."

Comment: This took me so long to find :P ... Thanks a lot Anurag!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array, but then you are using it as an object. This is possible because an array is also an object, but when it's serialised only the array content is included and the object properties are ignored.

The string in `b` will be `[]`, and the result in `c` is an empty array, not `undefined`.

Create an object instead, and it works:

```
var a = {};
```

Comment: @Rohan: You can use `[]` to access the object properties by name. Example: `var a = {}; var k = 'abc'; a[k] = 'asdf';`

Answer (score 1):

There are no 'indexed arrays' in javascript. There are arrays and objects. What you have there is an array, and it won't contain any indexes:

[image]

If you want something like that you should use an object: `var a = {}`.

Comment: try `b=a`; and then `b["something"]` . It will return `"hi"`

Comment: @Rohan yes, but if you serialize an array, you don't want it's `length` property between array values, right? now `something` becomes a property just like `length`.